# SyntaxError: Getting Unexpected Token, expected ;

Tags: javascript, k6

Here is my json file

```
{
"base_url": "https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users"
}
```

Here is my k6 script

```
import http from 'k6/http';
import { check } from 'k6';
import { sleep } from 'k6';

const dataset = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(require("./data.json")));
export let options = {
vus: 10, // Number of virtual users to simulate
duration: '1m', // Duration of the test in minutes
};

export default function () {
// Send an HTTP GET request
let response = http.get(dataset.base_url);

// Assert the response code is 200
check(response, { 'Status is 200': (r) => r.status === 200 });

// Add additional assertions using check()

// Sleep for 1 second before executing the next iteration
sleep(1);
}
```

When I am running my code I am getting error

SyntaxError: Getting Unexpected Token, expected ;

```
{
"base_url": "https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users"
          ^
}
```

hint="script exception"

Comment: What's the point of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`?

Comment: And you're getting the error because `require()` is assuming that the file is JavaScript, not JSON.

Comment: In this example, require('./data.json') imports the contents of the data.json file as a JavaScript object. The JSON.stringify() function converts the JavaScript object to a JSON string, and then JSON.parse() converts the JSON string back into a JavaScript object, creating a deep copy of the data.

Comment: After executing this code, the dataset variable will contain a deep copy of the data from the data.json file, allowing you to work with it independently.

Comment: By using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()), you ensure that any modifications made to the dataset variable will not affect the original imported data. This can be helpful when you want to manipulate or modify the data during your load test without altering the original dataset.

Comment: @AkashSrivastava - There is no reason to make that copy (in the above), and `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x))` is a terrible way to make copies in any case.

Comment: @AkashSrivastava wherever you found that advice, it is bad.

Comment: It's unusual to see `import` and `require` in the same module (though it's possible, with certain bundlers, or with the `createRequire` function in Node.js). As Pointy said, it looks like whatever that `require` is, it's not expecting JSON, it's expecting JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy i was watching some tutorial there I get that . 
Having said that, I am new to k6 and javascript and I am trying to store my environmental variable in json file and trying to use in k6 script . Can you please suggest me how we can achieve data parameterization in k6.

I have also gone through the official k6 doc and there they have only explain you can pass the value of env variable direct from the console 

https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/environment-variables/

could you please suggest

Comment: Storing configuration stuff as JSON is not a bad idea. You can use ordinary Node facilities like `.readFileSync()` and then `JSON.parse()`. There is no reason to make a deep copy, generally; configuration data is usually treated as read-only anyway.

Comment: `require()` expects the file to be JavaScript code, not JSON data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Value is not an object: undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76393134/typeerror-value-is-not-an-object-undefined). You must not use `require`, but `open` to read JSON files. I don't know why you posted two questions with basically the same content and one containing the answer for the other?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [k6 documentation](https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/init-context/open/) you should be able to [open](https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/init-context/open/) the local file:

```js
import http from 'k6/http';
import { check, sleep } from 'k6';

const dataset = JSON.parse(open('./data.json'));

export const options = {
  vus: 10, // Number of virtual users to simulate
  duration: '1m', // Duration of the test in minutes
};

export default function () {
    // Send an HTTP GET request
    let response = http.get(dataset.base_url);

    // Assert the response code is 200
    check(response, { 'Status is 200': (r) => r.status === 200 });

    // Add additional assertions using check()

    // Sleep for 1 second before executing the next iteration
    sleep(1);
}
```

You could use a [SharedArray](https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/k6-data/sharedarray/) with a more extensive dataset. And the example for [data parameterization](https://k6.io/docs/examples/data-parameterization/) can also be helpful.

I hope this helps!