# TypeError: Value is not an object: undefined

Tags: javascript, performance-testing, k6

Here is my data.json file

```
"base_url": "https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users"
```

Here is my k6 Sample.js

```
import http from 'k6/http';
import { check } from 'k6';
import { sleep } from 'k6';
import {open} from 'k6';

const jsonData = JSON.parse(open(__ENV.resourseURL));
const baseURL = jsonData.base_url;

export let options = {
vus: 10, // Number of virtual users to simulate
duration: '1m', // Duration of the test in minutes
};

export default function () {
// Send an HTTP GET request
let response = http.get(baseURL);

// Assert the response code is 200
check(response, { 'Status is 200': (r) => r.status === 200 });

// Add additional assertions using check()

// Sleep for 1 second before executing the next iteration
sleep(1);
}
```

and when I am running it via command

k6 run --env resourseURL=data.json Sample.js

it is giving me an TypeError: Value is not an object: undefined

Comment: Did you read the error? Get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them! The error should tell you what line it's coming from.

Comment: Just one tip, when you import multiple things from the same file you should only do it once, like this: `import { check, sleep, open } from "k6"`

Comment: Also there is no `Value` in the code you posted

Answer (score 1):

Why did you add the line `import {open} from 'k6';`? [`open`](https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/init-context/open/) does not need to (and must not) be imported. Simply remove this line and your script should work.

```
import http from 'k6/http';
import { check, sleep } from 'k6';

const jsonData = JSON.parse(open(__ENV.resourseURL));
const baseURL = jsonData.base_url;

export let options = {
  vus: 10, // Number of virtual users to simulate
  duration: '1m', // Duration of the test in minutes
};

export default function () {
  // Send an HTTP GET request
  let response = http.get(baseURL);

  // Assert the response code is 200
  check(response, { 'Status is 200': (r) => r.status === 200 });

  // Add additional assertions using check()

  // Sleep for 1 second before executing the next iteration
  sleep(1);
}
```